# Jquery Validation Plugin groups depends custom function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to get Minimum Price and Maximum Price fields to work correctly using JQuery Validator plugin. Neither field is required and users can enter a number in either one But, when both have values, then I want to make sure that the Minimum field is smaller or equal to the Maximum field.

It works when I click the submit button but not with the inline editing.

Here is what I have for the HTML:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
    <div class="control-group" style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
        <input id="shopping_request_min_price" name="shopping_request[min_price]" placeholder="at least...." />
        <input id="shopping_request_max_price" name="shopping_request[max_price]" placeholder="no more than..." />
        <div id="price_msg"></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This is what I have for the script:

```
    $('#myform').validate({
    groups: {
        minStrict: ' "shopping_request[min_price]" "shopping_request[max_price]" '
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") === "shopping_request[min_price]" || element.attr("name") === "shopping_request[max_price]") {
            return error.replaceAll($('#price_msg'));
        } else {
            return error.insertAfter($element);
        }
    },
    rules: {
        "shopping_request[min_price]": {
            number: true,
            min: 0,
            minStrict: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#shopping_request_max_price").val().length > 0 && $("#shopping_request_min_price").val().length > 0;
                }
            }
        },
            "shopping_request[max_price]": {
            number: true,
            min: 0,
            minStrict: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#shopping_request_max_price").val().length > 0 && $("#shopping_request_min_price").val().length > 0;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        return $(element).closest(".control-group").removeClass("success").addClass("error").css('padding-bottom', '40px');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        return element.text("OK!").addClass("valid").closest(".control-group").removeClass("error").addClass("success").css('padding-bottom', '40px');
    }
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod('minStrict', (function (value, el) {
    return +($("#shopping_request_min_price").val()) <= +($("#shopping_request_max_price").val());
}), "Min price must be less than or equal to max price");
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvw5qjyw/6/)

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or should be doing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or should be doing?

I think you may have misunderstood the `groups` option.  It's for combining the error messages from two or more fields into one.  It it not a rule/method, nor does it have anything to do with validation.

In your case, the `groups` option is broken because your field names have brackets and need to be surrounded in quotes.  It only appears to be working thanks to your custom `errorPlacement` function.

> It works when I click the submit button but not with the inline editing.

Not quite.  Notice that if you click over to the other field and click back, then it also triggers a new message.

---

1. Fixing your `groups` option...

   ```
   groups: {
       minStrict: 'shopping_request[min_price] shopping_request[max_price]'
   },
   ```
2. Fixing your `errorPlacement` now that `groups` is working properly...

   ```
   errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
       if ($(element).has('[name^="shopping_request"]')) {
           $('#price_msg').html(error); // put the message in your div
       } else {
           error.insertAfter(element); // default
       }
   },
   ```
3. When using `highlight` to do something on error, you would use `unhighlight` to undo it when the error is cleared.  Re-working a bit...

   ```
    highlight: function (element) {
       $(element).closest(".control-group").removeClass("success").addClass("error").css('padding-bottom', '40px');
   },
   unhighlight: function (element) {
       $(element).closest(".control-group").addClass("success").removeClass("error").css('padding-bottom', '40px');
   },
   success: function (element) {
       element.text("OK!").addClass("valid");
   },
   ```

Note:  You do not need to put `return` in front of every jQuery line in these callback functions.  `return` only gets used in certain circumstances.

Ok, now it's working normally, but you still need to click out of the field to trigger the validation...

https://jsfiddle.net/uvw5qjyw/8/

This is happening because of your `depends`.  The `minStrict` rule is not getting evaluated because `depends` is saying it's not yet active.  You have to click out of the field in order to activate this rule before it's evaluated.

The workaround for this is to force re-validation using `.valid()` every time you key-up.

```
$('[name^="shopping_request"]').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

**DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/uvw5qjyw/10/**

---

**NOTE**:  You also had a console error caused by including the `additional-methods.js` file before the jQuery Validate plugin.  It needs to come after.

Comment: Thank you Sparky.  That was an awesome explanation and exactly what I needed.  It works perfectly now.  Thanks again!